# ember-data does not add get parameter to request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to retrieve information through a REST request and set up a RESTAdapter like this:

```
   App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
       url: 'http://whatever.local'
   });
```

Ember is doing a GET request but is not appending a parameter if I try do to a `this.store.find('entry', 11)` or `this.store.findQuery('entry', {foo:'bar'})`

Additionally it does not send the request to the url I defined. It just sends it to the host the app is running on.

Therefore I'm guessing I initialize the Adapter not properly, but cant seem to find the answer what I am doing wrong.

```
App.OverviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        console.log(params);

        var entries = this.store.findQuery('entry', {periodDate: params.period_id});
        return entries;
    }
});
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in EmberData 1.0.beta.1, the adapter option is `host`, not `url` (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#host-and-namespace-configuration) in the [transition guide](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)):

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://whatever.local'
});
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that helps with the host part :) do I have to set up anything for the get parameter adding to the request?

Comment: @Martin-Mueller to add query params, we just use find e.g. this.store.find('post', { foo: 'bar' })

Comment: I'm doing the same, but the weird thing is that the parameter does not gets appended. (updated my post with code for route)

Comment: @Martin-Mueller you are doing it correctly. master is broken right now https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1407

Comment: aaahhhhh, thanks gerry. I was just debugging the code ember-data and clicked "step into" a lot :) There was a small time frame when it worked last week and I thought "wtf" :) thank you very much.

Comment: @Martin-Mueller it should be fixed now